# Change service call URL from html Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

My html is relatively simple: I enter a value in each `input` and click the `button` to search. It looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="myDropDown" onchange="FillMap(this)">
              <option value="11-01-2017">11-01-2017</option>
              <option value="12-01-2017">12-01-2017</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" name="FromDate">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" name="ToDate">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button">Search</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <div>
        <div id="MapDiv" ></div>
    </div>
```

My javascript looks like the following. As you can see, the call to service `GetSales` has fixed parameters (*2018-01-21 and 2018-02-05*). I need to replace these two values with the input values in the html. This service returns coordinates that will then be plotted to the map.

So to summarize, I click on the html button, and the web service will be called with the values entered in the html form as parameters:

```
function FillMap(control)
{

    portsMap.dataLoader.url = "http://OUR_SERVER/Service1.svc/GetLocationTotals/" + control.value;
    portsMap.dataLoader.loadData();
}
var portsMap;
AmCharts.loadFile( "http://OUR_SERVER/Service1.svc/GetSales/2018-01-21/2018-02-05", {}, function( data ) {
    var latlong = AmCharts.parseJSON(data);

portsMap = AmCharts.makeChart( "MapDiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "http://OUR_SERVER/Service1.svc/ShowFailures/11-01-2017",
    "postProcess": function(data, config, chart) {
      var areas = data.areas;
            console.log(areas);
      data.images = [];
      for (var i in areas) {
            for (var x in latlong) {    
                if (areas[i].id == latlong[x].location) {   
                    circlelat = latlong[x].latitude;    
                    circlelong = latlong[x].longitude;  
                      data.images.push( {   
                      "longitude": circlelong,  
                      "latitude": circlelat,    
                      "title": areas[i].id, 
                      "value": areas[i].value,  
                      "description": sitetext
                        });                         
                }   
            }   
      }
    return data;
    }
  },
"listeners": [{
  "event": "clickMapObject",
  "method": function(e) {
    ChangeUrl(e.mapObject.id);
  }
}]
} );
} );
```

The issue is that I don't exactly know how to pass parameters to `AmCharts.loadFile`. I was able to change `dataLoader` through a function call, but I'm not sure if I can use this with `AmCharts.loadFile`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any unique identifiers on either your `<input>` elements or your submission button, but fortunately you can use **[`.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)** and **[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)** to target them respectively.

You'll want to attach an event handler to the submission that passes through both variables once the button is clicked, and then combine the two `<input>` variables with the URL using string concatenation:

```js
var submit = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
submit.addEventListener("click", submit);

var from_date = document.getElementsByName("input")[0];
var to_date = document.getElementsByName("input")[1];

function submit(from_date, to_date) {
  AmCharts.loadFile("http://OUR_SERVER/Service1.svc/GetSales/" +
    from_date + " / " + to_date, {}, function(data) {}
  });
}
```

This will load the file from `http://OUR_SERVER/Service1.svc/GetSales/{from_date}/{to_date}` once the button is clicked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the first four lines would go inside a function called by the button click?

Comment: Well the first two lines are simply *creating* the button click, as you don't appear to have any functionality tied up to that in your example. You could even chuck the two `var` date initialisers into the `submit()` function itself, and then you'd only have to call `submit()` from your button.

Comment: I would only need to include the first two lines within `<script>` tags?

Comment: Correct. The first two lines are placed outside of any function, just inside `<script>` tags. They're essentially doing the same thing as adding `<button onclick="submit()">`. Having said that, I missed that I should have used `getElementsByTagName` rather than `getElementsByName` to target the button; I've corrected that now.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I hadn't realized I could convert the code from `AmCharts.loadFile` into a function and simply call it. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify: the first two lines are not needed if I have `<button onclick="submit()">`? Thanks.